Error: Cannot find module 'next' in Docker / Next 14 / Node 20 / React 18
i am currently working on a React Next project that was running fine on Node 16.19. I upgraded Node to v20.14, Next from v12.4 to v14.2, Yarn from v1.22 to v4.3, and most of the other dependencies to their newer versions. After some trouble with migration, it works loacally in VSCode by running my usual script: "dev": "turbo run dev --parallel" on the root package.json.
But now I'm having problems with the Docker container. The deployment job runs through without an issue, and an image is created. But my Docker container exits immediately after running the image. In the logs, I see this error:
2024-06-28 10:26:02 node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1148
2024-06-28 10:26:02   throw err;
2024-06-28 10:26:02   ^
2024-06-28 10:26:02 
2024-06-28 10:26:02 Error: Cannot find module 'next'
2024-06-28 10:26:02 Require stack:
2024-06-28 10:26:02 - /app/apps/web/server.js
2024-06-28 10:26:02     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1145:15)
2024-06-28 10:26:02     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:986:27)
2024-06-28 10:26:02     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1233:19)
2024-06-28 10:26:02     at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
2024-06-28 10:26:02     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/apps/web/server.js:16:1)
2024-06-28 10:26:02     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1358:14)
2024-06-28 10:26:02     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1416:10)
2024-06-28 10:26:02     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1208:32)
2024-06-28 10:26:02     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1024:12)
2024-06-28 10:26:02     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:174:12) {
2024-06-28 10:26:02   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2024-06-28 10:26:02   requireStack: [ '/app/apps/web/server.js' ]
2024-06-28 10:26:02 }
2024-06-28 10:26:02 
2024-06-28 10:26:02 Node.js v20.15.0

The Dockerfile:
FROM node:20-alpine AS builder

# Set up environment
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

# Install Corepack and set Yarn version
RUN corepack enable
RUN yarn set version stable

# Install root project dependencies
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install

# Copy project files
COPY . .

# Install dependencies
RUN yarn dlx turbo prune --scope=web --docker

# Build the application
RUN yarn dlx turbo run build --filter=web...

# Intermediate stage for installing application dependencies
FROM node:20-alpine AS installer
WORKDIR /app

# Copy necessary files
COPY .gitignore .gitignore
COPY --from=builder /app/out/json/ .
COPY --from=builder /app/out/yarn.lock ./yarn.lock

# Install application dependencies
RUN yarn install

# Copy built artifacts and configuration files
COPY --from=builder /app/out/full/ .
COPY turbo.json turbo.json
RUN yarn dlx turbo run build --filter=web...

# Runner stage
FROM node:20-alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app

# Set up user permissions
RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs
USER nextjs

# Copy necessary files from installer stage
COPY --from=installer /app/apps/web/next.config.js .
COPY --from=installer /app/apps/web/package.json .
COPY --from=installer --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/apps/web/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=installer --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/apps/web/public ./apps/web/public
COPY --from=installer --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/apps/web/.next/static ./apps/web/.next/static

# Expose port and set environment variables
EXPOSE 3000
ENV PORT=3000

# Command to start the application
CMD node apps/web/server.js

Initially, I suspected an issue with AWS ECS deployment, prompting me to install Docker Desktop. However, the problem persists even locally in Docker Desktop, leading me to believe the issue lies within the Dockerfile or another aspect of the project setup.
I've also extensively modified the Dockerfile in attempts to resolve the issue, mainly focusing on ensuring correct folder copying and paths. But these changes mostly caused the deployment jobs to fail outright.
Dont now if related but:
In Docker Desktop, under the 'Inspect' section on the Container, I noticed that it seems to still use Yarn version 1.22.22 even after I upgraded it to v4.3.1. Could this be causing the problem?
Any hints or guidance would be greatly appreciated as I'm currently a bit stuck...

You don't seem to be copying or installing a node_modules tree in the final build stage.  Do you need an additional COPY line, or to RUN NODE_ENV=production yarn install?

Thank you for your comment!
Yes, as I understand it, the packages should be automatically bundled within the standalone folder when setting output: "standalone" in the next.config.js, and the node_modules should not need to be copied manually. At least this worked before the updates.
I tried RUN NODE_ENV=production yarn install but it sadly did not fix it.

This fixed it for me:
With the new Yarn version, there was the addition of .yarnrc.yml, which initially contained only one line:
yarnPath: .yarn/releases/yarn-4.3.1.cjs.
I had to add nodeLinker: node-modules here to ensure the generation of node_modules.
Plus despite having read that the outputFileTracingRoot setting is outdated and supposedly inactive, I also had to keep these two lines in my next.config.js:
output: "standalone",
experimental: { outputFileTracingRoot: path.join(__dirname, "../../") },
If anyone has a better understanding of what these changes exactly do and why they are necessary, feel free to comment.

Thanks for sharing this.  I had exactly the same issue as you and adding this was the key to fixing it.
